# Get docker image LABELS via Kubernetes API

Tags: kubernetes

Hello is there a way to get the docker image labels from running containers via the Kubernetes API?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get docker-image labels from kubernetes API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45599353/get-docker-image-labels-from-kubernetes-api)

Answer (score -3):

Well if you want to get the labels much more easier, you can just add a --show-labels when getting your pods:

```
kubectl get po --show-labels
kubectl get deploy --show-labels
kubectl get all --show-labels
```

you can also use the api only to list or watch or filter pods but unfortunately, labels need to be specified to do so 
you can see some examples as follow:

```
?labelSelector=environment%3Dproduction,tier%3Dfrontend
?labelSelector=environment+in+%28production%2Cqa%29%2Ctier+in+%28frontend%29
```

This answer was 100% based from Kubernetes documentation, you can also check https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/ for more info or more specefic usage, anyhow, do not hesitate to send me a message/mail/tag if future questions

Comment: If you need more Advanced info, you can also check the Downward API https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/

Comment: The commands in the answer reveal labels configured on Kubernetes Pods and Deployments.
These labels do not correlate to image metadata, such as Dockerfile's `LABEL` or [OCI annotations](https://github.com/opencontainers/image-spec/blob/main/annotations.md).
Therefore, this does not answer the original question.

EDIT: Also the downward API is not helpful here, unfortunately. Downward API passes information from a Pod to its containers.
The question demands for a way to pass information from container to Pod.