# Kubernetes API custom image metadata

Tags: kubernetes

I try to use the Kubernetes API to read metadata via annotations from container images. The metadata is applicable to every instance of the respecting image and is needed in order to run any resulting container properly. Following this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45599353/get-docker-image-labels-from-kubernetes-api) it is not possible to read Docker image labels from the kubernetes API directly.

My next thought was to use custom annotations added to the image manifest, although this seems to be a pretty hacky solution for such a "simple" task. Anyway if I add the annotations to the manifest using docker, I see no way to read them from the Kubernetes API.

I think I am on the completely wrong track here. This seems to be a rather simple task which other people likely have implemented already...anyway I cannot find any further information regarding this. Is it really that hard to read image metadata via kubernetes before deploying a container of that image?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Edit:

The reason I am asking is because I want to grant the containers of specific images access to specific serial USB devices (e.g. FTDI232) on diverse host systems. Since I have no idea which path (e.g. /dev/ttyUSB0) will be assigned to the USB devices, I wrote a program that is monitoring USB devices and, in case an appropriate device is plugged in or gets plugged in, creates the container and passes it the corresponding path. From inside the container I want to access the serial device via a static, non-changing path (e.g. /dev/FTDI232)

Comment: Can you say a little more about what you're trying to do?  If the metadata is part of the image, why can't it be included as environment variables or a config file that's also built into the image?

Comment: @DavidMaze take a look at my edit

Comment: Your edit suggests that the real problem is totally different that the initial question suggested. Can you confirm that what you actually want is to have access to e.g. /dev/ttyUSB0 from the container (in k8s) with static path? So that what container sees is /dev/FTDI232 but actually its accessing /dev/ttyUSB0. Please confirm if this is correct.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. I want to use the metadata on images to tell my program in which serial device the respecting image is interested and whats the exact path the image expects.

Comment: Does it have to be metadata on images? Would you accept the answer not using metadata but still solving your problem?

Comment: That depends on the answer I guess. It does not have to metadata on images but anything that can be bound to an image in registries.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The K8s API is limited when it comes to this, I believe the abstractions for container image metadata are at lower level and probably left out for a reason.  You can always look at the [CRI spec](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2016/12/container-runtime-interface-cri-in-kubernetes/) to see what's supported (note that the doc is out of date so you might have to look at the code).

If the end goal is to use Kubernetes to run your workloads it sounds like the more feasible route here is just to write a script that reads that image manifest outside Kubernetes and create the manifest files that you need to run your workloads after (based on that metadata) and then finally apply it to your cluster.

If you are using a common container image registry you could also write something that pulls the images from that registry to just pick metadata and metadata changes.